# Suppose $f:G→H$ is an epimorphism and N is a normal subgroup of G. Prove that there exists a homomorphism from $G/N$ onto $H/f[N]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Task :
***Suppose $f:G→H$ is an epimorphism and N is a normal subgroup of G. Prove that there exists a homomorphism from $G/N$ onto $H/f[N]$.***

I'm really confused as to why half of this information even matters.

My attempt:
Define a function $f(gH)=hN^{'}$ and similarly $f(aH)=vN^{'}$ where $g,a\in G,h,v\in H,N^{'}=f(N)$
This function is a homomorphism simply by rules around coset arithmetic.

So, $ f(gaN)=hvN^{'}=hN^{'}vN^{'}=f(gN)+f(aN)$

So its a homomorphism. However, why would it be surjective?

Comment: Your attempt is... hard to parse. What is $h$? What is $v$? You never say. Then you conflate multiplicative notation with additive notation. Since you never tell us who $h$ and $v$ is, it is difficult to know if your $f$ is really even a function!

Comment: @Hristmar If we adopt the notation $σ$ respectively $σ'$ for the canonical surjections $G \to G/N$ respectively $H \to H/f(N)$, the induced quotient morphism $g \colon G/N \to H/f(N)$ satisfies the relation (a commutative diagram, ultimately) $g \circ \sigma＝\sigma' \circ f$. The right hand side is a composition of surjections, therefore itself a surjection. In general, if a composition of two maps is surjective then the left factor of that composition must also be surjective. Apply this to $g$, the left factor of the composition in the left hand side of the above relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is surjective${}^*$, and $N\triangleleft G$, then $f(N)\triangleleft H$. To verify this, note that given $f(n)\in f(N)$ and $x\in H$, there exists $g\in G$ such that $f(g)=x$. Then
$$xf(n)x^{-1} = f(g)f(n)f(g^{-1}) = f(gng^{-1})\in f(N),$$
with the last assertion because $N$ is normal in $G$.

Thus, $f(N)\triangleleft H$, and so we can form the quotient $H/f(N)$. Now compose the map $f$ with the quotient map $\pi\colon G\to H/f(N)$ to get a surjective homomorphism $G\to H/f(N)$. This is surjective because it is a composition of surjective maps.

Finally, note that if $n\in N$, then $\pi(f(n)) = e$, because $f(n)\in f(N)$. Thus, $\pi\circ f$ factors through $G/N$ (Isomorphism Theorem) to get a map $\theta\colon G/N\to H/f(N)$ with image the same as $\pi\circ f$; that is, $\theta$ is surjective. If you trace the morphisms through, you’ll see that the map is given by $\theta(gN) = f(g)f(N)$.

Why is the information you have necessary?

1. If $f$ is not surjective, then it is not necessarily true that $f(N)$ is normal in $H$. For example, the map that sends $C_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$, to $S_3$ by mapping the generator to the permutation $(12)$ does not map the normal subgroup $C_2$ of $C_2$ to a normal subgroup of $S_3$. So it will not even make sense to talk about $H/f(N)$.
2. If $f$ is surjective but $N$ is not normal, then it does not even make sense to talk about $G/N$.

So you *do* need to know that $f$ is surjective and that $N$ is normal.

${}^*$: I don’t like using “epimorphism” as a synonym for “surjective”; epimorphism means “right cancellable morphism”, and while all epimorphisms in the category of all groups are surjective, the same is not true in some natural categories of groups, or in categories like the category of all rings. So it’s best to get out of the (bad) habit.

Comment: Very understandable. Thank you for explaining and sorry about the notation mistakes, its been a long day.